# generating .cc and .h from .msg in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

It has been said in the documentation of omnet++ that the .cc and .h files are generated automatically from .msg file . However, after having defined my .msg file the .cc and .h files have not been generated. What should I do?

Comment: Writing an .msg file will not cause the .cc and .h file appear from nowehere. You should actually build your project (successfully) to see the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

So, have you got any errors during the compilation(build)?
As manual said, the message compiler is normally invoked automatically for your .msg files during build. Maybe an error avoid the files were generated

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build/compile your code after creating the `.msg` file.

- from command line (in linux)

  ```
  make makefiles
  make -j <number_of_cores>
  ```
- from OMNeT++ IDE (in linux & windows)

  `ctrl+b` or choose *Build* by right-clicking your project

Answer (score 0):

They should be created automatically after rebuild. Also make sure that you call them in your simulation, if a host is generating the packets so you should check all the configuration files in that host (APP Generators and Encapsulation).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to *Clean project* first before *Build*.